# Can't insert now() in PHP

Tags: php

I am a beginner programmer trying to insert the the `now()` value into my field `date`. I have achieved this before and copied the structure word by word but still does not work. I have also viewed other stackoverflow questions and I think that my database structure is correct. Here is INSERT php code:

```
try{
    $conn = new mysqli("xxxxx", "xxxxx", "xxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxx"); 
    $userid = $_GET['userid'];
    $title = $_GET['title'];
    $comment = $_GET['comment'];

    $query = "INSERT into enquiries (userid, title, comment, Resolved, date)
    values ('" . addslashes($userid) . "','" . addslashes($title) . "','" . addslashes($comment) . "', N, now() )"; 
    $result = $conn->query($query); 

    if (!$result){ 
        $json_out = "[" . json_encode(array("result"=>0)) . "]";    
    }

    else { 
        $json_out = "[" . json_encode(array("result"=>1)) . "]";
    }       
        echo $json_out;
        $conn->close();
}
```

This set of codes worked and inserted values before I added `now()`
Here is my table structure:
[image]

Here is my other table structure that inserted now() just fine:
[image]

Comment: have you tried the SQL query in the phpMyAdmin first?

Comment: `$query = "INSERT into enquiries (userid, title, comment, Resolved, `date`)
    values ('" . addslashes($userid) . "','" . addslashes($title) . "','" . addslashes($comment) . "', 'N', now() )"; 
    $result = $conn->query($query);`

Comment: "addslashes" just no this does noting this code is very insecure

Comment: on of simple way add today date $today=date('Y-m-d'); add $today variable in ur query

Comment: **WARNING**: `addslashes` is completely useless for SQL escaping. Use an actual [SQL escaping method](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "Resolved" value needs to be in quotes, because you have it defined as a varchar.  This would be the case for any of the "char" family of datatypes.

```
$query = "INSERT into enquiries (userid, title, comment, Resolved, date)
    values ('" . addslashes($userid) . "','" . addslashes($title) . "','" . addslashes($comment) . "', 'N', now() )";
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This solved my problem! Never would have thought bout this since my "Resolved" value worked before without '', very peculiar!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes database has some restrictions.. So try using like this NOW() than now() or else use CURDATE().